# Two relationated tables, two foreign keys to the same reference. How do I join the data?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have the following tables:

[image]

**users** table data:

[image]

**history** table data:

[image]

And I want to get the whole history with the corresponding user name in each row, something like this:

```
| id | seller | client |
| 1  | John   | Peter  |
| 2  | John   | Peter  |
| 3  | Peter  | John   |
```

I have tried with `INNER JOIN` but I can't get the result because of course I can't query something like:

```
SELECT history.id, users.name AS seller, users.name as client
```

So what is the corresponding query to get that result?

Comment: Ive accepted the edit suggestions and edited the title. I didn't know that I can make different alliases to join twice the same table. I think this question is usefull, even if its a duplicate one, it is more short and clean than the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join twice:

```
select h.id, us.name seller, uc.name client
from history h
inner join users us on us.id = h.sellerid
inner join users uc on uc.id = h.clientid
```